# How to remove an option from select element after it's been selected in another select element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks in advance for any help! 
I have five select elements on the same form, and with the same options. I would like to have any selected option be removed from the other four select elements when the user clicks on them. I'm hoping to use a simple JS for this. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

This is what I have tried so far

JS:

```
<script>
    function removeSelected(obj){
    var sel1= document.getElementsByName('program1');
    var sel2= document.getElementsByName('program2');
    var sel3= document.getElementsByName('program3');
    var sel4= document.getElementsByName('program4');
    var sel5= document.getElementsByName('program5');

    obj.remove(sel1.selectedIndex);
    obj.remove(sel2.selectedIndex);
    obj.remove(sel3.selectedIndex);
    obj.remove(sel4.selectedIndex);
    obj.remove(sel5.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```

Where "program1, program2, etc." is the name of each select element

HTML:

```
<label for= "cName" class= "floatLabel">Please Select A Program<span>*</span></label>
                   <select name="program1" class="floatCtrl" id="cName" required="required" onchange="document.getElementById('program1_text').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" onfocus=" removeSelected(this)">
                   <option value="" selected>  </option>
                   <option value="1">  Break Dancing 7/2/2013 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="2">  Guitar 7/10/2013 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="3">  Drums 7/12/2013 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="4">  Drawing 6/19/2013 $78.00</option>
                   <option value="5">  Watercolor Painting 6/19/2013 $78.00</option>
                   <option value="6">  Kids Art 8/7/2013 $30.00</option>
                   <option value="7">  Book Making 6/12/2013 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="8">  Writing 6/25/2013 $50.00</option>
                   <option value="9">  Dog Obedience 6/5/2013 $45.00</option>
                   <option value="10"> Skateboarding 7/30/2013 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="11"> Dodgeball 8/7/2013 $5.00</option>
                   <option value="12"> Jumprope 8/6/2013 $25.00</option>
                   <option value="13"> Swimming 6/2/13 $40.00</option>
                   <option value="14"> Games 7/2/2013 $20.00</option>
                   <option value="15"> Tennis 1 6/18/2013 $30.00</option>
                   <option value="16"> Tennis 2 6/25/2103 $30.00</option>
                   <option value="17"> Tennis 3 7/2/2013 $25.00</option>
                   <option value="18"> Tennis 4 7/16/2013 $25.00</option>
                   <option value="19"> Tennis 5 7/23/2013 $35.00</option>
                       <option value="20"> Tumbling 5/23/2013 $25.00</option>
                   <option value="21"> Backyard Discovery 7/20/2013 $5.00</option>
                   <option value="22"> Applegate Discovery 7/27/2013 $10.00</option>
                   <option value="23"> Mountain Adventure 8/3/2013 $10.00 </option>                                                 
                   </select>

                   <input type="hidden" name="program1_text" id="program1_text" value="" />
```

I'm trying to call removeSelected(this) in the onfocus event.

Comment: That's swell :) What have you tried so far? Did you try searching for how to remove select elements? searching for how get which element is selected? detecting the user click? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Yes I have, sorry! I will update.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    options[i].onclick = function(){
        var value = this.value;
        console.log(value);
        for(var x = 0; x < options.length; x++){
            if(options[x].value == value){
               options[x].parentNode.removeChild(options[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/stJqd/

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me Kevin. Thank you anyway!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.